# Почему при выводе динамического массива в консоль не нужен оператор разыменования?

Tags: c++, указатели, память

Прохожу тему динамических массивов и при написании кода стало интересно, почему при выводе динамического массива не нужен оператор разыменования? Почему нужен в арифметике указателей я понял.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

/*
*   динамический массив
*/



void main()
{
    int size = 0;
    cout << "enter value " << endl;
    cin >> size;
    int* arr = new int[size];//выделение динамической памяти для массива

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)//Заполнение динамического массива
    {
        arr[i] = rand();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)//Вывод динамического массива
    {
        cout << arr[i] << "\t";
        cout << *(arr + i) << endl; //арифметика указателей
    }
    delete [] arr;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По сути выражение `arr[i]` — это и есть `*(arr + i)`.

Разыменовывать можно указатель, но `arr[i]` таковым не является.

`arr[i]` — это `i`-ый элемент массива, начинающегося по адресу `arr`. Т.е. элемент, находящийся по адресу `arr + i`. А чтобы получить значение по этому адресу, нужно разыменование — `*(arr + i)`.

Comment: понял, спасибо большое. А не подскажете как мне для себя лучше охарактеризовать ,"arr[i]" что бы точно понимать , что так делать нельзя. Или это нужно просто принять как правило?

Comment: Немного дописал ответ. Так понятнее?

Comment: Да , понятнее, спасибо.